# How to achieve a Windows Phone-like "tiled" 3D transformation using CSS3

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm attempting a CSS3 animation effect using a 3D transformation/transition.  I have an HTML container, which is effectively divided up into "tiles" with another layer that sits on top.  What I'd like to do is create a "flip" effect on individual tiles.

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KwRX7/8/), except where one of the layers is plain HTML (eg, text).

```
.sub {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s linear;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
}​
```

After pondering this for a while, I'm not sure it's even possible.  Here's what I attempted.

- Container with some text as the back layer.
- Layer tiles on top; set one tile's opacity to zero, creating a "window".
- Now apply the transformation to the back layer.
- Add a third layer on top, that is the same as the first layer.

This almost works, but not really;  the "window" flips as it should, but of course the top layer is still visible over the window, [ruining the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/FpRnn/5/).

Is there any way to accomplish this partial-flip effect?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think that this -> http://ryanlowdermilk.com/2012/03/windows-8-metro-tiles-with-html-css3-and-javascript/ is what you need...

Comment: This is really nifty, but it's not quite what I was looking for.  Honestly my question should probably be closed as too localized, anyway.